# Org-mode: pipe source block output as stdin to next source block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I try to pipe the output of one source block to the next source block as standard input.
Here an example of what I have so far:

```
Create stdin data:
#+header: :exports code
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src sh
echo "That goes to the next"
#+end_src

#+name: piped
#+RESULTS:
: That goes to the next 

Use "piped" as stdin:
#+header: :exports results
#+header: :stdin piped
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src sh
VALUE=$(cat)
echo "I got:"
echo "$VALUE"
#+end_src
```

My problems with this are:

- I have to manually create the result of the first block by hitting `C-c C-c`
- the result must be included in org-buffer (large output not needed otherwise)
- the result must be named manually

Is there a workaround or better way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a simple way to fix your code by naming the src block instead of results:

```
#+name: piped
#+header: :exports code
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src sh
echo "That goes to the next"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: That goes to the next 

#+header: :exports results
#+header: :stdin piped
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src sh
VALUE=$(cat)
echo "I got:"
echo "$VALUE"
#+end_src

#+results:
: I got:
: That goes to the next
```

Comment: Very good, thanks, that really helped.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar use case, and rolled a simple exporter which let me use json-mode for the source/input from stdin:

```lisp
;;; ob-passthrough.el ---  passthrough evaluator          -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; this ob evaluates the block as ifself, so it can be used as input
;; for another block

(require 'ob)

(defun org-babel-execute:passthrough (body params)
  body)

;; json output is json
(defalias 'org-babel-execute:json 'org-babel-execute:passthrough)

(provide 'ob-passthrough)
;;; ob-passthrough.el ends here
```

Then, add `(passthrough . t)` to org-babel-list-langauges, and here it is in action:

```
#+NAME: json-test
#+BEGIN_SRC json
  {"greet": "hello, world"}
#+END_SRC

#+HEADER: :stdin json-test
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
  jq .greet
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: hello, world
```

Comment: This is super useful. I used this and added another for XML as well.

Comment: Amazingly useful! Should really be a part of org-babel! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Call a src block from another using "noweb" references (see `(info "(org) Noweb reference syntax")`):

```
#+name: input
#+header: :exports code
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src sh
echo "That goes to the next"
#+end_src

#+header: :exports results
#+header: :results output :noweb no-export
#+begin_src sh
VALUE=$(<<input>>)
echo "I got:"
echo "$VALUE"
#+end_src

#+results:
: I got:
: That goes to the next
```

Comment: That is cool, good to know, thanks. Unfortunately the second source code block really has to use stdin. The use of `cat` in the shell was only a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this problem is to name the input as an EXAMPLE or a QUOTE block if the input is truly static.  Something like this:

```
#+NAME: some-json
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
{"label": "Hello json"}
#+END_QUOTE
```

or an EXAMPLE if you prefer:

```
#+NAME: some-json-2
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
{"label": "ehlo json"}
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

then reference those named blocks in the code you wish to evaluate; here we use the QUOTE example:

```
#+NAME: the-code
#+HEADER: :stdin some-json
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
jq .label
#+END_SRC
```

Since the value of the `some-json` block is static, there is no need to evaluate it.  Evaluating `the-code` block gives:

```
#+RESULTS: the-code
: Hello json
```

Answer (score 0):

I love [Matt Curtis](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/18526/matt-curtis)'s answer and use it all the time in my personal config.

However I often find I want to parameterize the payload in some way, so I also made this variant that lets you use the source block as a template:

```lisp
(defun org-babel-execute:$template (body params)
  "Pass BODY through verbatim except for replacing variables defined in PARAMS."
  (let ((var-defs (org-babel--get-vars params)))
    (pcase-dolist (`(,var-name . ,value) var-defs)
      (let ((var (format "$%s" var-name)))
        (setq body (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote var) value body)))))
  body)

(defalias 'org-babel-execute:json 'org-babel-execute:$template)
```

Then you can do

```
#+NAME: json-test-template
#+BEGIN_SRC json :var name=""
  {"greet": "hello, $name"}
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: foo-json
#+CALL: json-test-template(name="foo")

#+RESULTS: foo-json
: {"greet": "hello, foo"}
```